# cellForRowAtIndex not being called in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

I've currently got a single working `UISearchController` implemented inside the header view of a `UITableViewController`. I wish for my other views to also follow suit but some are `UICollectionViewController`s. Is there a way to create one `UISearchController` and just call them across all the views within the headers? All of the results must show in a table.

I had attempted to create one for each view but the `UICollectionViewController` was giving me some problems. I couldn't figure out how to set and update a table for the search controller. It wouldn't allow me to override the `tableView` methods as i guess the controller is a `CollectionView`.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Should also add that the search method/data will be the same across all of the views. See how the stock iOS Music app uses search bars as an example.

EDIT 2:

I've nearly cracked it (I think). I've setup a singleton "SharingManager", within this i have 3 arrays. Now I have 2 views, one named ArtistsView and one SearchTableViewController. The Search view contains all of the table methods and the ArtistsView communicates with that using:

> self.searchResultsController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: SearchTableViewController())

I also copy the variables within the singleton to variables that are within the SearchTableViewController.

The issue i'm having now is that the cellForRowAtIndexItem method is not being called. All the other ones are, i can even see the section headings are being displayed. I have set up various println() statements to see where i could've gone wrong, the numberOfRowsInSection is also returning the correct numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: You now have two questions here. You should open a new one rather than editing the original in order to keep any previous answers relevant, and the question/answer quality high. Also when it comes to things "just not working" you'll get better help if you show some code.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past to solve this kind of issue, and what seems to be the most flexible is to have it so that when you tap on the searchbar, your app actually transitions to another view controller that handles the search and search results.

1. Fake search bar button on each screen you wish to use it.
2. When tapping the search bar, screen cap your current view controller.
3. Set the screen cap to the background of your search results controller, blurred or darkened a bit if you like, so it doesn't interfere with the search results.
4. Transition between your previous view controller and the new search results controller with a fade.

You'll be able to give the user the impression that they never left the original screen they were on.